# How to open mywebview fragment on my home page

Tags: android

How to implement oncreate web view on my application  main fragment home page.onclick it opening the html file on opera mini browser. 
fragment_geo_njoro.xml is GeoNjoroFragment xml file

```
  package sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp;        

    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.webkit.WebView;        

    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class GeoNjoroFragment extends Fragment {        

        public GeoNjoroFragment() {        
            // Required empty public constructor
        }        

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_geo_njoro, container, false);

            WebView myWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.R.id.webview);
            myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.hivisasa.com/wb/nakuru/news/113249");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return view;        
        }        
    }
```

Comment: please mention your whole code for here. Activity as well as xml file and manifest file.

Comment: The code is working the problem remains where the html opens .I want it to open at application layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set webview client to open web page in webview. Add this line before you load the url

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

and add this method in your class

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
}
```

It should work like charm.

Comment: It 100% working thanks i am growing android too each and every day